# VB.NET get time from database using a datareader

Tags: vb.net

I have a table in my database containing the open and closing times for the different days of the week. I use an sql statement to retrieve these values, using a datareader and that works fine.
I just dont know how to get these times in time format.
I tired this.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetString("open_time"))
```

But i get the date aswell as the time.
Please help.

Comment: You're converting it to datetime, so yes, you will in fact get a date, and a time.  What format are you trying to pull back exactly (i.e. are you looking for 24 hour clock format, or 12 hour, etc.)?

Comment: The DateTime type always has a Date and a Time portion.  If you only want the time, just use the Hrs, Mins Secs portion.  This assumes that the column type in the database is datetime; in that case, you should be using `reader.GetDateTime()`

Comment: I'm looking fro 24 hour format and they are stored in my database a type time.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I am doing the same thing as the OP, came across this topic then found a solution elsewhere.

```
StartTime = Nothing
If (Not rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("StartTime"))) Then
    StartTime = Date.MinValue.Add(rdr.Item("StartTime"))
End If
```

where StartTime is a Date? and the SQL field is a Time.
Although StartTime is a Date, it can be used in time comparisons like this:
    If StartTime.Value <= TimeOfDay Then